# Confusion with identity operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information

[image]

In the above example why the identity matrix ie ∑|x〉〈x|...is taken as ∫|x〉〈x| dx  from negetive to positive infinity? or alternatively can someone explain  the steps to expand the ket ψ into x basis

Comment: what do you mean by complete

Comment: @marmot I think you mean that $\left| x \right>$ is complete.

Comment: @DomDoe You are right.

Comment: @kay the integral $\int \left| x \right> \left< x \right| dx$ is just the continuous form of the sum  $\sum_i  \left| x_i \right> \left< x_i \right|$. Since the position basis $\left| x \right>$ is indeed continuous, we need the integral formulation to create the infinite dimensional identity matrix $I$.

Comment: by continious form of summation do you mean this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula  if so why the function equals to zero at the infinities ie n and m of the above formula?

Comment: if not why do we take  continious summation as a integral i mean for a function f(xᵢ)  summation is tge sum of all values [f(x₁) fx₂() f(x₃)...)] while integral is the area under tge graph of f(x) and i dont understand how fir continious functions area can equal sum of all values of f(x)...any help is much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

First, the concept of complete basis. If $|x\rangle$ form a complete basis, which it did, in $R$, then $1=\sum_{all ~ x}|x\rangle\langle x|$, because "complete" means that "there's nothing else other than the vector space spanned by the basis", so you may consider whatever you were thinking regrading $x$ to be expressed as a linear combination of $|x\rangle$.

Second, summation again. You should review your question ([Integral as summation in quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/491895/integral-as-summation-in-quantum-mechanics) ) In this case, $x$, being the continuous space, was continuous, thus you need to take $\sum_{all ~ x_i} |x\rangle\langle x|=\int_{domain ~ of ~ x} |x\rangle\langle x| dx =\int_{R} |x\rangle\langle x|dx=\int _{-\infty}^\infty |x\rangle\langle x| dx$